# Get the ID for the default organization through API

Tags: api, organization

Is there any way to get the "default organization" contact id through the API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default organization contact id is stored in civicrm_domain table. You can use domain api to retrieve the contact id i.e

```
  $result = civicrm_api3('Domain', 'getvalue', array(
      'sequential' => 1,
      'return' => "contact_id",
      'id' => 1,
    ));
```

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: If you run multi-domain, you'll need to specify which domain you want instead of the `'id' => 1` above